# How do I convert a UCS2 string into UTF8?

Tags: ruby, unicode, utf-8, ucs2

How to convert a string that is in UCS2 (2 bytes per character) into a UTF8 string in Ruby?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should look into [iconv](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/iconv/rdoc/index.html), which is part of the Ruby standard library.  It is designed for this task.

Specifically,

```
 Iconv.iconv("utf-8", "utf-16", str).first
```

should handle the conversion.

Comment: UCS2 isn't exactly the same as UTF-16 (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16/UCS-2)

Answer (score 2):

Because chars in most cases string in UCS2 encoding can be represented as UTF-16 string (in UTF-16 char with codes bigger than 0x10000 is rarely used) I think use of Iconv is better way to convert strings.
Sample code:

```
require 'iconv'

ic = Iconv.new 'UTF-8', 'UTF-16'
utf8string = ic.iconv ucs2string
```

Comment: I'm now happily using UCS-2LE in place of UTF-16.

Answer (score 1):

With Ruby 1.9:

```
string.encode("utf-8")
```

If the string encoding is not known, you may need to set it first:

```
string.force_encoding("utf-16be").encode("utf-8") # Big-endian
string.force_encoding("utf-16le").encode("utf-8") # Little-endian
```