# Ruby on Rails and utf-16

Tags: ruby-on-rails, utf-16

I have a translation script that allows for translators to submit arabic translations, but for some reason Ruby doesn't like the encoding. Is there a way to encode the submitted text as utf-16?

Answer (score 2):

How are translations submitted? A web browser will never submit form data as UTF-16, even if the form that generated the submission was on a UTF-16-encoded page. It's generally a bad idea to use UTF-16 on the web; as an encoding that isn't ASCII-compatible, dealing with it is a pain and there are server and client bugs to watch out for. Instead, always use UTF-8.

I guess UTF-16 in an uploaded file is possible. In that case I would sniff the first two bytes for a UTF-16LE/BE BOM and if present [transcode the file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033104/converting-a-ucs2-string-into-utf8-in-ruby) to UTF-8 before doing any further work.

Comment: they are being submitted via ajax. the problem occurs if html elements are submitted along with the translation. I am allowing `<b>, <i>, <a>` tags along with the submission

Comment: That doesn't sound like much to do with UTF-16 then. XMLHttpRequests are sent in UTF-8. What is the request body you're sending, and what is the error you're getting?