# How to convert array of UCS-2 bytes to UTF-8 string in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, unicode, utf-8, string-conversion, ucs2

I have an array of UCS-2LE encoded bytes in Ruby and since this is my complete beginning with Ruby I'm struggling to convert it to UTF-8 string, I have the same code in PHP & Java working just fine.

In PHP I'm using iconv library, but in Ruby iconv has been deprecated:

```
$str = iconv('UCS-2LE', 'UTF-8//IGNORE', implode($byte_array));
```

In Java I'm using:

```
str = new String(byte_array, "UTF-16LE");
```

Bytes in the array are encoded as 2 bytes per 1 character, how to perform similar conversion in Ruby? I've tried a few solutions but it didn't work for me. Thank you.

Comment: Did you read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033104/how-do-i-convert-a-ucs2-string-into-utf8 ?

Comment: `byte_array.pack("C*").force_encoding("UTF-16LE").encode("UTF-8")` should work

Comment: @Stefan it works just fine, I build the array putting items as .chr types, I've removed .chr and add your code and it works just fine, one thing I don't understand, how does it work with C* type while the documentation states that C is a char (and not wide char)?

Comment: `C` interprets an integer value as a 1-byte char, i.e. `[65].pack("C")` converts `65` (`0x41`) to `"A"` (`"\x41"`). The result is a string with ASCII-8BIT encoding. `force_encoding` then reinterprets the bytes.

Comment: ok I get it, thank you :)

Comment: @BartoszWójcik I've posted a more detailed answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming a byte array:

```
byte_array = [70, 0, 111, 0, 111, 0]
```

You can use [`Array#pack`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-pack) to convert the integer values to characters (`C` treats each integer as an unsigned char):

```
string = byte_array.pack("C*")       #=> "F\x00o\x00o\x00"
```

`pack` returns a string with ASCII-8BIT encoding:

```
string.encoding                      #=> #<Encoding:ASCII-8BIT>
```

You can now use [`String#force_encoding`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/String.html#method-i-force_encoding) to reinterpret the bytes as an UTF-16 string:

```
string.force_encoding("UTF-16LE")    #=> "Foo"
```

The bytes haven't changed so far:

```
string.bytes                         #=> [70, 0, 111, 0, 111, 0]
```

To transcode the string into another encoding, use [`String#encode`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/String.html#method-i-encode):

```
utf8_string = string.encode("UTF-8") #=> "Foo"
utf8_string.bytes                    #=> [70, 111, 111]
```

The whole conversion can be written in a single line:

```
byte_array.pack("C*").force_encoding("UTF-16LE").encode("UTF-8")
```

or by passing the source encoding as a 2nd argument to `encode`:

```
byte_array.pack("C*").encode("UTF-8", "UTF-16LE")
```